# In Android widget, how to catch the index for current view on screen in AdapterViewFlipper?

Tags: android, widget

I'm working on Android widget with an AdapterViewFlipper inside. As we know, AdapterViewFlipper rotates automatically through its **views**. 
My question is, how to catch the index for which the view is showing on screen? 
I tried using getViewAt() method in its Adapter, but found later that there is some problem. getViewAt() is not only called each time showing the view, but also each time when AppWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(). So it's hard to distinguish these two events.

Is there any listener for the AdapterViewFlipper or its adapter that we can know the index of the view currently being showed on screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about getDisplayedChild() ?

Comment: Thanks, pskink. But this does not work as getDisplayedChild() must be applied on AdapterViewFlipper, whereas in widgets AdapterViewFlipper is inside RemoteViews, and we are not able to apply this method to it.

Comment: Keep track of the last view requested in getViewAt in the RemoteViewsAdapter?

Comment: Please have a look at following link: 
It solved my problem. Bigggg thanks 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958186/adapterviewflipper-in-app-widget-setpendingintenttemplate-and-setonclickfilli

Answer (score 1):

Combining the answers from [Listener for ViewFlipper widget flipping events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813108/listener-for-viewflipper-widget-flipping-events/3813179#3813179)

and

[android; setting in/out animations on AdapterViewFlipper: Unknown animator name translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532929/android-setting-in-out-animations-on-adapterviewflipper-unknown-animator-name)

You can set an **Animator** on an AdapterViewFlipper (Note this is difference to the Animation used in a ViewFlipper)
You can then create an AnimatorListener and add it to the "In Animation" and it will trigger when the child is displayed and you can then call getDisplayedChild() to return the index.

Example code

```
// Setup AdapterViewFlipper
mAdapterViewFlipper = (AdapterViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.AdapterViewFlipper);
mAdapterViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000);

// Set Some Animations
mAdapterViewFlipper.setInAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.animator.left_in);
mAdapterViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.animator.right_out);

// Create a AnimatorListener
mAnimatorListener = new AnimatorListener() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {}

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {}

    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {}

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
        int displayedChild = mAdapterViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild();
        Log.w(TAG, "onAnimationEnd view index:" + displayedChild);
        int childCount = mAdapterViewFlipper.getCount();
        if (displayedChild == childCount - 1) {
           // Do what you want before wrapping to first view
           //mAdapterViewFlipper.stopFlipping();
        }
    }
};

// Add the Listener to the In animation
mAdapterViewFlipper.getInAnimation().addListener(mAnimatorListener);

// Set adaptor just before start so view with index 0 triggers Listener
mAdapterViewFlipper.setAdapter(adapter);

// Start Flipping
mAdapterViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
```

The R.animator.left_in and R.animator.right_out are files in the "res/animator" directory with content like:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="-1500"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:duration="600"/>
```

Every time a view is flipped to you will get a Log event in this example like:-

```
TAG onAnimationEnd view index:0
TAG onAnimationEnd view index:1
TAG onAnimationEnd view index:2
TAG onAnimationEnd view index:3
TAG onAnimationEnd view index:4
TAG onAnimationEnd view index:0
```