# Don't understand how to use animation with adapterViewFlipper

Tags: android

I don't understand how to use animation with adapterViewflipper.
I'm in API13, and I use an adapterViewFlipper in a Fragment.

So in My xml file I only have:

```
        <AdapterViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/avfPicturesSite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradientbackground"
             >

        </AdapterViewFlipper>
```

and I dynamically create ImageView in getView().

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        view = new ImageView(context);
        viewHolder.img = (ImageView) view;
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }


    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

    viewHolder.img.setImageURI(getItem(position));

    return view;
}
```

I browse images with buttons where I try to set the animations. It seems that sitePicturesFlipper.setInAnimation(Context context, int resourceID) is waiting for an AnimatorSet.

```
    nextSitePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //sitePicturesFlipper.setInAnimation(R.animator.right_in);
            sitePicturesFlipper.setInAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.left_in);
            sitePicturesFlipper.setOutAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.right_out);
            sitePicturesFlipper.showNext();
        }
    });
```

and the animators are declared like that:

left_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="5000" android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="5000" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
 </set>
```

right_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="5000" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="5000" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

But when I click on the button, I get a RuntimeException Unknown animator name: translate!

I also tried to use ObjectAnimator instead, like that:

```
    nextSitePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            sitePicturesFlipper.setInAnimation(getActivity(), R.animator.left_in);
            sitePicturesFlipper.setInAnimation(getActivity(), R.animator.right_out);
            sitePicturesFlipper.showNext();
        }
    });
```

and the xml files are:

left_in2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
                android:propertyName="yFraction"
                android:valueType="floatType"
                android:valueFrom="-1"
                android:valueTo="0"
                android:duration="600"/>
</set>
```

right_out2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
                android:propertyName="yFraction"
                android:valueType="floatType"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:duration="600"/>
</set>
```

but in that case I get java.lang.ClassCastException: android.animation.AnimatorSet cannot be cast to android.animation.ObjectAnimator

So I don't understand to set and use it correctly and it's quite difficult to find example using adapterViewFlipper on Internet, except in Thai, but I'm not very comfortable with Thai language...

So, how to use animation with adapterViewFlipper?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, I finally found that **ObjectAnimator** is the rigth way to declare an animation with **adapterViewFlipper**.
Anyway, it doesn't like the tags "<"set">" and "<"/set">" at least as I wrote them. And I didn't find how to declare several property animations. I admit that I still have problems to really understand Android documentation...

Waiting for infos if someone has ideas about it.

So, to solve the first problem I had, a complete set of ObjectAnimator to slide images left and right in an adapterViewFlipper is:

left_in.xml, declared in animator folder

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
            android:propertyName="x"
            android:valueType="floatType"
            android:valueFrom="-1500"
            android:valueTo="0"
            android:duration="600"/>
```

right_out.xml

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
            android:propertyName="x"
            android:valueType="floatType"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="1500"
            android:duration="600"/>
```

right_in.xml

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
            android:propertyName="x"
            android:valueType="floatType"
            android:valueFrom="1500"
            android:valueTo="0"
            android:duration="600"/>
```

left_out.xml

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
            android:propertyName="x"
            android:valueType="floatType"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="-1500"
            android:duration="600"/>
```

Then to use animations:

```
    myAdapterViewFlipper.setInAnimation(getActivity(), R.animator.right_in);
    myAdapterViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(getActivity(), R.animator.left_out);
    myAdapterViewFlipper.showNext();
```

or

```
    myAdapterViewFlipper.setInAnimation(getActivity(), R.animator.left_in);
    myAdapterViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(getActivity(), R.animator.right_out);
    myAdapterViewFlipper.showPrevious();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Works, thanks :)

Comment: Also be careful to put these animations in "animator" folder and not in "anim".

Comment: I had the same problem and saw that the AdapterViewAnimator has an overload of setInAnimation that takes an ObjectAnimator as parameter. Thus, you can create this object programatically. In order to animate more than one property, you have to use PropertyValuesHolder.

PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", -500f, 0f);
PropertyValuesHolder pvhAlpha = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("alpha", 0f, 1f);
ObjectAnimator objAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(myAdapterViewFlipper, pvhY, pvhAlpha).setDuration(300);
myAdapterViewFlipper.setInAnimation(objAnimator);

Comment: Hello, i want these animations to give sliding effect (left slide in, left slide out, right slide in, right slide out). How can i achieve this ?

Comment: bro @fralbo do you have a more animation

Comment: Checking the documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#Property) the set property should be functional on this case. I guess it's just not possible to do several objectAnimators to work together (or sequencial) with the <set> tag on some objects. I had this same issue trying to animate the in and out of my view flipper